# How to send a request to webservice in Android?

Tags: android, django, web-services

I write a webservice in django

if i use from terminal command like this

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT
    --data '{"name": "Change","address": "/api/v1/user/1/"}' 
    http://localhost:8000/api/items/1/
```

How to write command it to Android request to webservice?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://localhost:8000/api/items/1/");
httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

String data = // put your JSON object here
tmp = new StringEntity(data, "UTF-8");

httpPut.setEntity(tmp);
response = httpClient.execute(httpPut, localContext);

Srting result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: how to use between POST PUT DELETE ?

Comment: Oh sorry it was PUT, missed that one. There is a HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpPost and HttpGet just use the one you need and set the headers and  data entity. I'm changing the code example to Put in a sec..